# What is the best way to create continuous html parsing?

Tags: python, parsing, cron

I have an html page in my local network. I need to get some figures every 1 second and save in database.
What is the best way to do that?

I think it may be parser is written using python. But how to do it that script keep parsing constantly. Maybe using cron?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are monitoring what seems to be an automated HTML page that changes as often as 1/sec, then you can probably get away with using a regex to extract your data. (There are many warnings in SO about parsing HTML with regex, but this may be one of the exception cases, since it appears to be an automated page, perhaps some form of factory sensor automation, or stock ticker. Automated pages usually maintain a consistent format, so using a regex to extract specific fields might just work.)

As for running the parser 1/second, you can do this in your Python script itself, using something as simple as `time.sleep` inside a `while True` forever loop.